Grapping FB profile link via Sprinklr when contact is through messenger
Dears i want to ask  about FB ability to share the user profile link Via "Sprinklr" when the user is contacting the FB page Via messenger is this feature shared Via API from FB or is it a limitation
Use Case to explain the question

My business has a facebook page that is manager by Sprinklr
Customer is reaching to my Page Via DM (Private message)
Sprinkle is unable to capture the link that directs me to the customer Facebook profile

Ask  i need to know if this option is available or not  ||( in general either via sprinklr or other provider)

No, that is not available any more.
All Facebook still gives out via API, is a link for the user profile that will only work for friends of the user.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#fields:

link- A link to the person's Timeline. The link will only resolve if the person clicking the link is logged into Facebook and is a friend of the person whose profile is being viewed.

